# Geocoding - get all records within a boundry

Tags: mysql, geospatial, geocoding

Lets say I have a database of locations (countries, regions, cities, towns) with their lat/long co-ordinates.

E.g. I have the co-ordinates for England 52.16045, -0.70312

Is there a way for me to return all locations within the bounds of England if all I have are lat/long?

Do I need to polygonise the location...if so how would I do that if all I have are lat/longs.

For the record the database is Mysql.

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this in MySQL.  It would be much much easier to do in a programming language like PHP.

Comment: Those don't sound like bounds to me, they're center points. You would need the bounding boxes, or at least a search radius.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a polygon with the boundary of the state  you could use a ST_CONTAINS  feature of mysql geometry for find al the points inside the polygon

Assuming you have a table (points) the contain the  points and polygons  with polygon,  and each polygon is based on a polygon.name 
you could use

```
SELECT points.col1 
FROM polygons
INNER points ON  ST_CONTAINS(polygons.geom, Point(points.longitude, points.latitude)) 
    AND polygons.name = 'Your_name';
```

the ST_CONTAING just check if a geometry is contained  inside one other

Comment: @adam78 indeed https://www.openstreetmap.org/ has country based bounding boxes data which you can probably convert into a MySQL table which scaisEdge is talking about.

Comment: @RaymondNijland   www.openstreetmap.org  let available also the boundary of state and administrative area.. ..and are easily availabel because tipically the maps are in shp  ..

Comment: i know and roads, lakes, rivers, houses.. you can disable unwanted objects.. Yes most likely the country shaps(bounds) are available else where on the internet iam only giving openstreetmap.org as a example

Comment: @RaymondNijland how do I import/export the bounding boxes data from openstreetmap.org into mysql?

Comment: @scaisEdge importing entire openstreetmap into database will use up an huge amount of disk space?

Comment: @adam78 "importing entire openstreetmap into database will use up an huge amount of disk space? " Yes atleast [73 GB](https://planaet.openstreetmap.org) + storage engine/index overhead.. "how do I import/export the bounding boxes data from openstreetmap.org into mysql" You can convert a planet [OSM](https://planaet.openstreetmap.org) or country/continent OSM [downloads](https://download.geofabrik.de/) to [MySQL](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=9870)

Comment: I suggest you of take a look at the map  available on OSM downloading the maps  is shape  (or geojoson) format and look at the map in QGIS  .. once you have evaluated  which layer are useful for you then just import the data for these layer ..in DB..

Comment: @scaisEdge so just to be clear even if I create a geometry column using the lat/long for all the locations and if I have a location I would not be able to return all the locations from that geometry e.g. I create geom for england, london, manchester using lat/long. Then if I have england as the location I would not be able to return london and manchester unless I have a polygon table that has the boundry for england?

Comment: Why not  ... ST_Contains  .. work for all the geometry contained  in a (polygon) geometry  .. work when there is a full  (complete) intersect  between  geometries .... is important that all the geometries  use the same SR Reference System